# When will galaxies become unstable due to dark energy?

Tags: galaxies, dark-energy

When will galaxies become unstable due to dark energy? What will it be like for a civilization to observe their own galaxy going through this period of instability?

Comment: Why do you think galaxies become unstable due to dark energy? You are not limited to a few lines in your question - give context and references!

Comment: As the Hubble constant increases over time it will eventually become stronger than the gravitational attraction between objects at large distances such as the stars within a galaxy. Eventually even planets won't be able to stay in orbit around stars and so on.

Comment: I don't think, as of now, we are able to say with certainty when this would happened. Part of this due to the fact that we don't understand how strong dark energy is, or even what it is. Heck, we don't even know whether dark energy or gravity will be the dominate force in the far future. The debate "Big Rip vs Big Crunch vs Big Freeze". Thus, there is no accurate answer to your question. I am sorry. Fun little thing, you can check this diagram about the one possible future of the universe on BBC website. Go to this page, http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20140105-timeline-of-the-far-future

Comment: AFAIK, the prediction of the standard cosmology is that eventually DE dominates to the point that it starts ripping apart gravitational structures like galaxies. A reference wouldn't hurt the question, but assuming this is the future is well founded in physics (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all pretty well described in the Wikipedia page on the ["big rip"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Rip).

The Friedmann acceleration equation determines the evolution of the scale factor of the universe and can be written as
 $$\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} = -\frac{4\pi G}{3}\left(\rho + \frac{3P}{c^2}\right) $$
where $\rho$ is the energy density, and $P$ is the pressure, usually parameterized as $P = w\rho c^2$.

A cosmological constant has $w=-1$, which leads to
$$ \ddot{a} = \frac{8\pi G \rho a}{3}$$
And hence exponential growth. That's OK, galaxies can still survive in such a universe, held together by their self-gravity.

The "big rip" happens when $w<-1$. In this case, not only does the acceleration of the expansion increase with time, but the size of the observable universe shrinks at an increasing rate. Once this size is smaller than any particular structure, it cannot be held together. Eventually a singularity is reached when all points are infinitely separated - i.e. the scale factor becomes infinite. This occurs in a time
$$ t- t_0 = \frac{2}{3|1+w|H_0 (1 - \Omega_M)^{1/2}} \simeq \frac{11\ Gyr}{|1+w|},$$
where $\Omega_m$ and $H_0$ are the matter density and Hubble parameter now at time $t_0$.

Because of the accelerating nature of the process, the time at which galaxies would be ripped apart is very close to the end singularity (unless $w$ is very, very close to $-1$). So choose your $w$ and plug it into the formula. At present, the constraints on $w$ are not good enough to say what will happen.